# Simple Noob C++ Input/Output Question: Code Error

Tags: c++, io

Expected Behavior: Print out "What's your name?" and then ask User for Input. After that, print out "Hello " + Input.

Observed Behavior: Outright Crash, Failed to Build.

Code:

https://gist.github.com/Niki45nk/824c22fa394fad97e4d253fd810a8563

Comment: [Works for me](https://rextester.com/HML9520)

Comment: Works fine for me, maybe u can try just hello world program, if the program crash, the issue is your compiler

Comment: Hmm. I guess I should've pointed out I'm using Visual Studio to compile it. Though I don't know what's wrong there.

Comment: [Works for me](https://rextester.com/GCKZ55335) with MSVC, too.

Comment: So it crashed, or it failed to build? What was the build error? Have you tried cleaning or rebuilding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Found the Reason for the Errors. Turns out it was just my compiler being wierd.

Just needed to update it and the project itself, is all.

Still Thanks for the help though! And Sorry if this was obvious...